# delete the duplicate entries from column in csv file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a csv file having more than 10000 lines in two column .I have to delete the duplicate entries from column 1.
Sample input

```
col1,col3
od1,pd1
od1,pd4
od2,pd1
od2,pd2
od3,pd6
od3,pd688
od3,pg7
```

Sample Output

```
col1,col3
od1,pd1
,pd4
od2,pd1
,pd2
od3,pd6
,pd688
,pg7
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can handle this easily using an associative array with key as `col1`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} seen[$1]++{$1=""} 1' file

col1,col3
od1,pd1
,pd4
od2,pd1
,pd2
od3,pd6
,pd688
,pg7
```

Comment: just playing around :) `awk -vFS=, -vOFS=, 'seen[$1]++{$1=""}1' file`

Comment: `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` is considered better and safer that using `-v` twice

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with awk

The command would be

`awk -F"," '{if(!a[$1]++) print $0;}' file.csv`

Set the delimeter according to your csv format with the -F flag.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is sorted (by 1st field) then

```
$ cat f
col1,col3
od1,pd1
od1,pd4
od2,pd1
od2,pd2
od3,pd6
od3,pd688
od3,pg7

# Either
$ awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$1!=p{p=$1;print;next}{$1=""}1' f
col1,col3
od1,pd1
,pd4
od2,pd1
,pd2
od3,pd6
,pd688
,pg7

# Or
$ awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$1==p{$1="";print;next}{p=$1}1' f
col1,col3
od1,pd1
,pd4
od2,pd1
,pd2
od3,pd6
,pd688
,pg7
```